# onclick link update content with php refresh div box and show notification message box

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to create a code on click update the content in PHP, refresh the div box and show the notification message box.

file.html

```
<html>
<title>Submit Form without Page Refresh - PHP/jQuery - TecAdmin.net</title>

<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://rawgit.com/notifyjs/notifyjs/master/dist/notify.js"></script>
    <link href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Merriweather+Sans:400,300,700,800" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<script type="text/javascript">
    function SubmitFormData(cid) {
//        var id = $("#name").val();
        $.post("data.php?action=update", { id: cid },
            function (data) {
                $('#results').html(data);
                // $('#myForm')[0].reset();
                $(".results").notify("Updated " + cid);
            });
    }
</script>

</head>

<body>
    <a href="" onclick="SubmitFormData(1);">1</a>
    <a href="" onclick="SubmitFormData(2);">2</a>
    <br />
    ==============================
    <br />
    <div id="results1">
        <!-- All data will display here  -->
    </div>
    <div id="results2">
        <!-- All data will display here  -->
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

data.php

```
<?php
if ($_GET['action'] == 'update'){
if ($_POST['id']){
    echo 'Updated: ' . $_POST['id'];
    echo ' post';
}else{
    echo 'Updated: ' . $_GET['id'];
    echo ' get';
}
}
?>
```

The bugs are:

- The content in the refresh box disappears
- The refresh and notification message box I need to show in 1 and 2 because will have more rows
- Is not working the notification box message as the https://notifyjs.jpillora.com/

I really appreciate any help to build and fix this code.

Thank you.

Comment: Please ask separated specific question ([ask]). SO is not a debug assistance site

Comment: Multiple problems with the source code you have provided... `$('#results')` - `$(".results")`  You have no elements with the `ID` or `class`  of **results** Also if you find your page is refreshing/reloading you might want to add a `#`to your anchor tags `href` => `href="#"`